# Eclipse whitespaces for tabs

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Galileo, and I've gone:

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spaces for tabs

but the editor still inserts real tabs when I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. This is driving me crazy. How do I force eclipse to put in spaces for tabs? I'm editing Java files.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about :

- Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formater
- and, then, edit the formating style (it'll open another dialog)
- In that new dialog :

  - General settings > Tab policy => choose "Spaces only", instead of "Tabs only"
  - You can also set the "Tab size".

Comment: Thank you, been driving me crazy.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  *(I don't use Eclipse for JAVA development, but I've had exactly the same problem for PHP development a couple of times ^^ )*

Comment: So this raises another question: why is there a "Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spaces for tabs" that is apparently ignored by (at least) the Java and PHP editors which have their own (apparently identical) setting?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter. 
Click edit next to your active profile. 
Change your tab policy to Spaces Only